# MySQL Workbench update syntax faux error

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I am executing an 
        `UPDATE table1,table2` statement 
in MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 and my `UPDATE` command is marked red. The hover message says `Syntax error, unexpected UPDATE_SYM`

Everything worked fine, no errors, no warnings in execution of the script but I am curious to what this means or if my `UPDATE` would be better written as `UPDATE TABLE1 SET A=B JOIN TABLE2 ON X=Y`

Thanks,

Comment: `UPDATE Table1 JOIN Table2 ON X = Y SET A=B` -- syntax for mysql.

Comment: Problem solved - was leaving out my semi-colon from the statement above.